# All root drive items in one SharePoint have same IDs?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

This question is about root drive items in SharePoint drives, i.e. document libraries (because doc. libraries are backed by drives).

Namely, in a SharePoint site, I have multiple document libraries: the default one (called 'Documents') and a few more (let's call them DL1 and DL2).

To get the root drive item, in the drive backing DL1, I use this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/dl1-drive-id/root
```

I use a similar query to get the root drive item in the drive backing DL2.

However, all of those root drive items have the same ID. The drives, of course, have different IDs.

I tested this on two tenants and it's the same behavior. Is this expected?

Comment: I confirmed it on my test tenant. I created two Document Libraries and the /root for both has same ID. Can you submit it as a bug from Microsoft 365 Admin Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element IDs are not guaranteed to be unique outside of their parent scope (for this case, parent scope is root folder of the document library).

However, the fact that root elements in different document libraries have same IDs is the side effect of the SharePoint provisioning process. As Jeremy Kelley (one of PMs  that works on Microsoft Graph APIs for SharePoint) wrote in an answer to my question on Twitter: *"Most provisioning of things in SharePoint is optimized partially through the use of static templates to stamp things out rapidly.  Which means each thing created using that template has the same ID."*

Comment: Full discussion on Twitter: https://twitter.com/panjkov/status/1400561024995106818

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate: How do you retrieve Drive IDs?

You should first retrieve correct Drive ID based on the SharePoint site by performing

```
GET /sites/{siteId}/drive
```

or for the Microsoft 365 Group

```
GET /groups/{groupId}/drive
```

and then you can refer it by correct ID. You can test these queries in Graph Explorer https://aka.ms/ge

The official documentation for different use cases for retrieving drives is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks for that Dragan. Yup, I'm aware of those docs and am retrieving the docs in that way. `GET /sites/{siteId}/drive` gives only the default drive (doc. lib.) in a site. I used `GET /sites/{siteId}/drives` and used the IDs from that list.

Comment: I just checked in my tenant, and each of the document libraries that I retrieve in /drives collection has unique ID.

Comment: Ah, I misread it... you mean Drive ITEMS have same IDs...

Comment: That is correct, root drive items, i.e. `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/dl1-drive-id/root`

Comment: I confirmed it on my test tenant. I created two Document Libraries and the /root for both has same ID. Can you submit it as a bug from Microsoft 365 Admin Center?